# 'Case ' inside a 'group by ' clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am beginner in SQL Server, I want to write the following query in T-SQL, and I can't find out how to do it

```
SELECT 
    SUM(PROSPECTS), 
    MARQUE,
    LANGUAGE 
FROM
    USERS 

CASE Marque IN (0, 16, 30, 36) THEN Group BY MARQUE ELSE Group By Language
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Have you considered NOT having the case in the group by? You can have a calculated field in the SELECT with the case and then use that field to group by.

Comment: Sample data and expected output would help immensely. @TomTom No you cannot, unless you repeat the whole `CASE` or put it into an `APPLY` or derived table

Comment: @Charlieface You absolutely can, though you may need 2 selects. The outer select using the inner one as virtual materialized table and doing the grouping.

Comment: @TomTom That's called a "derived table" and is what I mentioned, and what I was saying is that you *cannot* do it in the `select` of the same level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close...

```
group by
  CASE Marque IN (0, 16, 30, 36) THEN MARQUE ELSE Language END
```

But also need to apply same context at the top

```
SELECT 
    SUM(PROSPECTS), 
    CASE Marque IN (0, 16, 30, 36) THEN MARQUE ELSE Language END MarqLang
FROM
    USERS 
group by
   CASE Marque IN (0, 16, 30, 36) THEN MARQUE ELSE Language END
```

Comment: It'll help the OP to show the corrected select list too: `SELECT SUM(PROSPECTS), CASE Marque IN (0, 16, 30, 36) THEN MARQUE ELSE Language END FROM ... GROUP BY CASE Marque IN (0, 16, 30, 36) THEN MARQUE ELSE Language END;` ... It's unlikely the OP will understand the 'functional dependence' issue, where selecting either `marque` and/or `language` directly is an error.